# Injected service is undefined, but works in other classes

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am puzzled: **I usually inject and use my LoggingService in other services and it works**. This is my very simple LoggingService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoggingService {
  //[...]  
  logInfo(obj: any) {
    if (this.logging) console.info('[INFO] ' + obj);
  }
}
```

In the following class, **my injected service is undefined**:

*interceptor.service.ts*

```
import { LoggingService } from './../logging/logging.service';
import { RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable, Injector, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IHttpInterceptor } from '@covalent/http';

@Injectable()
export class InterceptorService implements IHttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private logger: LoggingService) {
    console.log('logger = ' + logger); // UNDEFINED
  }

  onRequest(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    this.logger.logDebug(requestOptions); // Obviously does not work
    return requestOptions;
  }

  // [...] Other methods
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { InterceptorService } from './services/interceptor/interceptor.service';
import { CovalentHttpModule, IHttpInterceptor } from '@covalent/http';
import { LoggingService } from './services/logging/logging.service';

@NgModule({

  imports: [
    // [...]
    CovalentHttpModule.forRoot({
      interceptors: [{
        interceptor: InterceptorService, paths: ['**'],
      }],
    }),
  ],

  providers: [
    LoggingService,
    InterceptorService,
    // [...]
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**How is this class different from the other ones (where the injection works ?**

I also tried injecting the service using injector:

```
loggingService : LoggingService;
constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
// [...]
loggingService = this.injector.get(LoggingService);
```

**But it is always undefined.** What am I missing ?

The IHttpInterceptor class comes from the following framework:
https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/http

Comment: Do you inject ihttpInterceptor somewhere else and does it work? try to remove its injection and comment it use and check if it works. Also put logginservice import after the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Angular 4.3's Httpclient, I eventually gave up and wrote my own interceptor. The problem I had was probably related to Covalent's Interceptor service and configuration.